# Can't include from Google Cloud Storage with App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I've spent all day on this!! Why can't I include from my Google Cloud Storage from my App Engine app?

Here is my main.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "echo is working<br />";
include ("gs://myappid.appspot.com/test.php");
?>
```

Here is test.php:

```
echo "hello world!";
```

Here is my app.yaml:

```
application: myappid
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
  application_readable: true


# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

I have deployed this app and when I navigate to main.php, I just see the first echo `echo is working`.

My storage bucket is the default for the app: myappid.appspot.com. And both the bucket and test.php have got the permission of: USER | myappid@appspot.gserviceaccount.com | OWNER

And my php.ini is:

```
output_buffering = "On"
google_app_engine.disable_readonly_filesystem=1
google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets = "gs://myappid.appspot.com"
```

According to Google's docs, other SO questions and several blog posts, this should work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by altering the php.ini. I changed this:

```
google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets = "gs://myappid.appspot.com"
```

to

```
google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets = "#default#"
```